# Transfering data from one sql database to other in azure using external table

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I want to transfer data from one database to other in SQL 2017 Azure.
I am following this way: both database have same schema but need to transfer only one tables data from 1 db to other.....

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'e4a421f5-8f73-4c68-8a4c-f5c9dc429dde';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL dbCredential WITH IDENTITY = 'mlsqladmin', SECRET = 'e4a421f5-8f73-4c68-8a4c-f5c9dc429dde';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE restoredDatabase WITH

(

    TYPE=RDBMS,

    LOCATION='sqlazewdmlitbunkerpit001.database.windows.net',

    DATABASE_NAME='sqdazewdmlitbunkerpit001_back',

    CREDENTIAL= dbCredential

);   


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Admin].[Estimates2016] (

    [CommandId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedTimestamp] [datetime] NULL

)

WITH (

     DATA_SOURCE = restoredDatabase,
      SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo', -- This is the name of the schema on the host database
   OBJECT_NAME = 'Transactions' -- Name of the table on the host database
);
```

--Here transactions is a view in other database with the schema as mentioned in --Extimates 2016
like 
--create view transactions select * from Admin.Command
**--  Here everything is working fine except the last insert statement which is below and the error is
--Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
--Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is ---not --introduced with EXISTS.
--Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
--Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  Command ON   
INSERT INTO Admin.Command  values  ((select  * from Admin.ESTIMATES2016 )  ) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  Admin.Command OFF


SELECT * FROM ESTIMATES2016 WHERE YEAR = 2016;
```

Comment: --obviously we need to drop all those after data transfer is done....
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE Admin.Estimates2016;

DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE restoredDatabase;

DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL dbCredential;

DROP MASTER KEY;

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Admin.Command  values  ((select  * from Admin.ESTIMATES2016 )  )

remove values and brackets include the insert parameters

This worked for me might be simple but took more time to find

**INSERT INTO Admin.Command(CommandId,Name,Active,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,CreatedTimestamp,UpdatedTimestamp)  select * from Admin.Estimates2016 where CommandId not in (select CommandId from Admin.Command)**